# Fire event with the updated class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm changing the class of the link on click to `class2` & I want to trigger the event for `class2` instead of `class1`. I know I can manually check for new class & then trigger() it. Is there any other way?

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/usXa3/

Html:

```
<a href="#" class="class1">Click me!</a>
```

Jquery I had:

```
$('.class1').on('click', function(){
    console.log("class1 clicked");
    $(this).removeClass('class1').addClass('class2');
    $(this).off('click');
    //Do something here to fire class2 event.
});
$(document).on('click', 'class2', function(){
    console.log("class2 clicked");
});
```

My Solution - Looking for alternative:

```
$('.class1').on('click', function(){
    var thisClass = $(this).attr('class');
    if(thisClass == "class1");
    {
        $(this).removeClass('class1').addClass('class2');
    }
    else if(thisClass == "class2")
    {
        $(".class2").trigger( "click" );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one) like,

```
$('.class1').one('click', function(){
    alert("class1 clicked");
    $(this).toggleClass('class1 class2');
    //Do something here to fire class2 event. 
    $('.class2').on('click', function(){
        alert("class2 clicked");
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tMaw9/)

Comment: you can improve this by using toggleClass('class1 class2'); instead of add and remove class this will achieve the same result.

Comment: thank you .. this helps. will accept this as answer in a minute

Answer (score 1):

Try [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/usXa3/2/)

```
$('.class1').on('click', function () {
    console.log("class1 clicked");
    $(this).toggleClass('class1 class2');
    $(this).off('click').on('click', function () {
        console.log("class2 clicked");
    });
});
```

[.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)